# Redirecting to another folder using htaccess with cake

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, cakephp-2.3

Hello i'm stuck in the following situation

One of our developers is outside for the moment and i have never used cakePHP.

I have a site under certain domain

http://example.com

in his .htaccess of the project he has this

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

But i would like that when the user enters straight to http://example.com they get redirected to another page or folder in the root.

The site is hosted in godaddy but if i try to do a redirect using their panel it gets ommited because of the one within the project, i just want to send the user to an "under construction page" while leaving my customer with the possibility of checking his page, but not to the general audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$ page-under-construction [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!page-under-construction).+)$ app/webroot/$1 [L,NC]
```